# how to limit edit_form_after_title hook to page and post edit only?

Tags: posts, pages, hooks, editor

heelo, 
I want to use this great hook **edit_form_after_title**

it was announced on December 1, 2012:
http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/01/more-hooks-on-the-edit-screen/

**it curreclty hook for  :
post-new, post, page-new, page.**

how do I make it to work only in edit page/post  (**only post, page**)

thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd use a different approach, because **@Shazzad**'s solution seems too much global dependent, and **@s_ha_dum**'s needs 2 hooks instead of one.

I'd use [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function to get a [`WP_Screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen) object, then I'd look at its property to run (or not) something after the title:

```
function do_something_after_title() {
    $scr = get_current_screen();
    if ( ( $scr->base !== 'post' && $scr->base !== 'page' ) || $scr->action === 'add' )
        return;
    echo '<h2>After title only for post or page edit screen</h2>';
}

add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'do_something_after_title' );
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if there was any change during the time that passed from the original question but as of 4.0 you get the post as a parameter to the hook and all that is needed to do is to check the post type. If you wonder what happens when creating a new post the answer is that WordPress generates a dummy post if the post type set to the correct type.

```
function do_something_after_title( $post ) {
    if( 'post' !== $post->post_type && 'page' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<h2>After title only for post or page edit screen</h2>';
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'do_something_after_title' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Check post type using `$typenow` and `$pagenow` global variables.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' );
function myprefix_edit_form_after_title()
{
    global $typenow, $pagenow;
    if( in_array($typenow, array('post', 'page') ) && $pagenow == 'post.php' )
    {
        echo '<h2>This is edit_form_after_title!</h2>';
    }
}
```