# Add custom field to admin area witthout using a metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I am developing a plugin which uses custom post types. When creating a new custom post, I have a number of custom fields in the admin area within a meta box.

Is it possible to display these fields without having them inside the metabox - ideally without having to register a metabox at all? Much like how the title field and content field are displayed in the admin area for posts.

Please no suggestions to use a plugin or manually create a custom field using the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor, I wish to implement this with code. Same with hiding the metabox with CSS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the 'edit_form_after_title' action or 'edit_form_after_editor'
this would out put your html after the title or content respectively.

If i'm working with a custom post type that done not have a content are these are particularly useful and create a really nice look instead of meta boxes.

Comment: Yes, perfect! I was able to customize the logic thanks to this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166346/51823 too